# How to use Same Tool stripe controls in whole Windows Application using C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, forms

I want to Use Same toolstrips control on whole application Like I have a MDI for which has toolstrip and toostrips have few button I want to use these button on Child form with different functionalities any one have Git Code please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use inheritance.  Create a base child form with all the buttons you want then let the child forms be inherited from it.